# Level of Detail for 3D terrains/models in Mobile Devices (Android / XNA )

Tags: android, graphics, 3d, xna

I am planning to develop for WP7 and Android.

What is the better way to display (and traverse) 3D scene/models in term of [LoD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail)?
The data is planned to be island-wide (Singapore).

1) [Real-Time Dynamic Level of Detail Terrain Rendering](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3188/realtime_dynamic_level_of_detail_.php)
2) Discrete LoD
3) Others?

And please advice some considerations/algorithms/resources/source codes. something like [LoD book](http://lodbook.com/) also Okay.

Side note: I am a beginner in this area but pretty well-versed in C/C++. And I haven't read the [LoD book](http://lodbook.com/).

Related posts:
- [Distant 3D object rendering [games]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013675/distant-3d-object-rendering-games)
- [Chris Pruett's 3D benchmark for Android](http://groups.google.com/group/replica-island-coding-community/browse_thread/thread/ee9e86c727ca9b61)

Answer (score 2):

With modern hardware you should not be doing ad-hoc geometry fiddling for (C)LoD as is done in ROAM. Instead you should chunk the terrain up in blocks (organized in a quadtree or similar setup) and push it to the device in nice hardware-friendly batches.

See [Thatcher Ulrich's](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/chunklod.html) excellent [writings on the subject](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/sig-notes.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

As Ranieri already said best bet would be Thatcher Urlich's Chunked LOD.
If you have a bit more memory you can also try  [CDLOD](http://vertexasylum.com/2010/07/11/oh-no-another-terrain-rendering-paper/) (full C++ source code available).

Answer (score 0):

you may want to watch Chris Pruett's talk about [writing real-time games for Android](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/writing-real-time-games-android.html) at Google I/O 2010 (he's talking about LOD).

Comment: yes, I have watched that and last year's video. This year he talked about why apps/games should use LoD and or MipMapping rather than talking about how to do it and what algorithms to use